# Knex transaction is not working because of cannot read property 'then' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, knex.js

I am using Knex js on Node Express to do a transaction. The transaction involves insertion into two tables. For testing purpose I hard-coded the column names and their values.

```
db('table_1').where('id', 1) 
    .then(data => {
      if (data.length === 0) {
        db.transaction(trx => {
          db.raw(`insert into table_1 (id, f_name) values ('1', 'hello');`).transacting(trx)   
              console.log('works 1')

              .then(data => {

                return db.raw(`insert into table_2 (id, l_name) values ('1', 'kitty');`).transacting(trx)    
                  .then(data => {
                  console.log(data[0])
                })
            })
            .then(trx.commit)
            .catch(trx.rollback);
        })
          .then(() => res.sendStatus(200))
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
      }
    })
```

This first insert works because the console.log works but then I got the error of `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`. I read that this error happens when there is a missing `then` but I couldn't see the issue here.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You misplaced `console.log('works 1')` which now breaks a chain of dot-notation. The `.then` that follows it now is like a method on whatever `console.log` returns, and we all know it returns nothing (`undefined`) ... hence the error.

Comment: Silly me. Thank you so much.